# How to change switch conditions using Toggle button?

Tags: android, realm

I have a program which creates a list of to-dos that allows the user to set a date/time for the app to notify them about it. There's a checkbox that says 'Notify me' which is supposed to schedule the notification. But, in the main RecyclerView of the list, there is also a toggle switch that allows the user to turn off/on the notification after they've saved it. Problem is, the toggle switch doesn't seem to be changing the notification state.

```
holder.notifSwitch.setChecked(journalModel.isNotify());

    if(journalModel.getJournalDateNotify().getTime() > System.currentTimeMillis())
    {
        holder.notifSwitch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.notifSwitch.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

     holder.notifSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           if(!journalModel.isNotify())
           {
               createJournalFunction.updateJournal(realm, journalModel.getRealmJournalNo(),true);
           } else
           {
               createJournalFunction.updateJournal(realm, journalModel.getRealmJournalNo(), false);
           }
       }
     });
```

And here is the code for updating the Realm object:

```
public boolean updateJournal (Realm realm, final int realmJournalNo, final boolean isNotify){
    success = false;
    try{
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                final TblJournal tblJournal = realm.where(TblJournal.class).equalTo("realmJournalNo", realmJournalNo).findFirst();
                tblJournal.setNotify(isNotify);
                success = true;
            }
        });
    }catch (RealmException e){
        Log.i("INFO","update Retail Exception: "+e.toString());
        success = false;
    }finally {
        return success;
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code your are not updating `journalModel.isNotify= true` or `false` in on click. `journalModel.setIsNotify(true):/journalModel.setIsNotify(false):`

Answer (score 0):

```
 holder.notifSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // status="true"; //edit here
                switch_btn.setChecked(true);

            } else {
                // status="false"; //edit here
                switch_btn.setChecked(false);

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine, you just need to modify your `onClick` method.

```
holder.notifSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)v;
           createJournalFunction.updateJournal(realm, journalModel.getRealmJournalNo(),checkbox.isChecked());
       }
});
```